# add environment variables to activate file in a virtualenv for a Django project

Tags: django, virtualenv

I recently clone a django project and in the README file said that :

```
Edit .venv/bin/activate and add this environment variables.
```

::

```
  export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="thissite.settings.development"
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
  export LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8'
  export LANG='en_US.UTF-8'
```

So i built this virtual env and in this step should i just simply copy and past this environment variables to the activate file(where exactly?) or what?

The activate file :

```
# This file must be used with "source bin/activate" *from bash*
# you cannot run it directly

deactivate () {
unset -f pydoc >/dev/null 2>&1

# reset old environment variables
# ! [ -z ${VAR+_} ] returns true if VAR is declared at all
if ! [ -z "${_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH+_}" ] ; then
    PATH="$_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH"
    export PATH
    unset _OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH
fi
if ! [ -z "${_OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME+_}" ] ; then
    PYTHONHOME="$_OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME"
    export PYTHONHOME
    unset _OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME
fi

if [ -n "${BASH-}" ] || [ -n "${ZSH_VERSION-}" ] ; then
    hash -r 2>/dev/null
fi

if ! [ -z "${_OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1+_}" ] ; then
    PS1="$_OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1"
    export PS1
    unset _OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1
fi

unset VIRTUAL_ENV
if [ ! "${1-}" = "nondestructive" ] ; then
# Self destruct!
    unset -f deactivate
fi
}

# unset irrelevant variables
deactivate nondestructive

VIRTUAL_ENV="/home/majid/Documents/Website/.venv"
export VIRTUAL_ENV

_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH="$PATH"
PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"
export PATH
```

I really appreciate if anyone help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

export `KEY=VALUE` is the terminal command. Just copy paste this on terminal will work. If you want more control for your Django project I suggest you to install `pipenv` and create the file called `.env` in your root folder where manage.py present. The pipenv is recommended way to work with virtualenv and managing environment.

**.env**

```
 DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="thissite.settings.development"
 LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
 LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8'
 LANG='en_US.UTF-8'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `virtualenvwrapper`, there will be a `postactivate` file in which you can put your env variables.

Depends on how you have it set up, but its probably located somewhere like:

`/Users/<me>/.virtualenvs/<my_project>/bin`

Just paste those export statements in and they'll be available in you env when you activate it.

Comment: I'am using virtualenv and there isn't any file named postactivate?! should I create it manually?

Comment: are you using virtualenv? or virtualenvwrapper? postactivate will only be there if you're using virtualenvwrapper